# Setting a length limit to <p> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, limit, paragraph, string-length

What I need to accomplish is simple - set the limit of the length of paragraph elements to 60 characters. The jQuery script I have written is as follows:

```
$('p.classname').each(function(){
var paragraph = $(p.description).text();
var strlength = paragraph.length;
var maxlength = 60;
strlength < maxlength; 
});
```

I can still include more than 60 characters in the  elements.
How can I limit it to 60?

Comment: What's `strlength < maxlength;` supposed to do?

Answer (score 5):

A simple approach using `text()` with a callback which loops though all elements in the same way `each` will:

```
$('p.classname').text(function(i, txt) {
    return txt ? txt.slice(0,60) : txt;
});
```

One major problem in your code is `$('p.description').text();` will get text for all paragraphs in the page concatenated together. You need to isolate the instance of each paragraph. To do it within an `each` loop would be

```
$('p.description').each(function() {
    /* text for current paragraph */
    var text = $(this).text();
});
```

You are also using invalid selectors without quotes, and you never do anything with the text other than check its length.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you want to trim the contents to a max of 60 chars then

```
var maxlength = 60;
$('p.classname').text(function (_, text) {
    return $.trim(text).substring(0, maxlength);
});
```